# Images not showing in blade.php file

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

i try to show up image in blade file, but the image wont show, i wrote the rigth link but still not show
here is my code

```
  @if ($post->image == 'NULL')
  <!-- foto usahakan di crop 3x2 landscape-->
      <a href="{{ route('showpost', $post->slug) }}" class="mb-4 d block">
         <img style="width: 400px; height: 240px; overflow: hidden;"
            src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/white-transparent-leaf-on-mirror-260nw-1029171697.jpg" 
            alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
  @else
      <a href="{{ route('showpost', $post->slug) }}" class="mb-4 d-block"> 
        <img style="width: 400px; height: 240px; overflow: hidden;" 
             src="{{ $post->image_url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
  @endif
```

anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Need a little more info.
Which one isn't showing.  The default should be working.
So I'm assuming the one your having trouble with is the dynamic $post->image_url?
What do you get when you dump the var? `{{dd($post->image)}}`

Comment: your code perfectly worked.just checked what you get in {{$post->image}}

Answer (score 0):

if you already done php artisan storage:link command so type your path in src like -:

```
<img style="width: 400px; height: 240px; overflow: hidden;" src="{{Storage::url('your_path/'.$post->image}}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
```